# Object properties being wiped by fast changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form that uses server-side validation and coercion.

In Vue, the state of the form fields is held in an object called `instance`, on the data object. Each field's value is represented by a property of `instance`.

`onChange` of any field, `instance` is posted to an API method that returns validation results and a coerced dataset (coercion does things like adding spaces to phone numbers, capitalising postcodes etc.).

Vue takes the response and iterates through the coerced data, replacing the properties of `instance`. If a field has not yet been reached by the user it is skipped (There is a `reached` object that keeps track of which fields the user has made it to).

The issue that I'm having is that occasionally (when entering data extremely quickly from one field to the next) the input of the current field gets cleared when the coerced data is returned from the previous one.

Initially I thought that there must be some issue with the `reached` logic, and that the `null` data returned for the field that the user is working on is overwriting the current input. But this is not the case; I can see in my logs that fields are being skipped yet the input is still clearing.

I'm starting to think that this might be a bug with Vue. Or at least, something specific to how Vue handles the data/dom elements that I need to account for. Is there a way that setting `instance.foo` could cause `instance.bar` to be reset?

```
    //this is called onChange for any field.
    change: function(e) {
        this.$set(this.instance, e.name, e.value);
        this.setReached(e.name);
        this.validate(true);
    },

    validate: function(reachedOnly) {
        axios.post(this.validateUrl, this.getFormData(false)).then(response => {
            this.allErrors = response.data.errors;
            this.setFormData(response.data.values, reachedOnly);
            this.fieldNumberValidated = this.fieldNumberReached;
        });
    },

    setFormData: function(data, reachedOnly) {
        for (var fieldName in this.fieldNames) {
            var value = data[fieldName];
            if(reachedOnly && !this.reached[fieldName]){
                console.log('skipping - '+fieldName);
                continue;
            }
            if (value && value.date) {
                value = value.date.replace(/\.\d+$/,'');
            }
            this.$set(this.instance,fieldName,value);

        }
    },
```

*** UPDATE: ***

I think I know what's happening now.

1. Field A triggers change()
2. Data gets sent for validation
3. User starts inputting into field B
4. Validated data gets returned. And set on `this.instance`.
5. Vue skips field B because it isnt in `this.reached`
6. BUT `this.instance` is being updated and redrawn.

Field B may have text entered in its input but it hasn't been added to `this.instance` because it hasn't triggered `change()` yet. So `this.instance` is redrawn based on field B having no value, which in turn updates the input and wipes whatever may have been in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by having 2 different events on my input fields - one for `input` that updates `instance` and another on `blur` that sends the validation request.

```
change: function(e) {
    this.validate(true);
},

input: function(e) {
    this.$set(this.instance, e.name, e.value);
},
```

This ensures that the properties of `instance` are always in line with their related input fields, and so nothing gets erased when `instance` is redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer but just some thoughts.

I'm not certain about why a field is being *cleared*, however I would like to point out a concurrency issue you may have. If you're calling the API for each keypress, you're not guaranteed that they will respond in the correct order, and it could be that you are setting the form data to an old validation response which would cause you to lose any text entered into the textbox since the request was fired. Also it's generally a good idea not to spam the server with too many requests.

At a minimum you should probably debounce the API calls, or use `blur` instead of `change` event, or you could implement some logic that cancels any pending validation request before firing another one.

Is there any particular reason why you are using `this.$set`? It should only be used if you're adding a property to an object.

> Initially I thought that there must be some issue with the reached logic, and that the null data returned for the field that the user is working on is overwriting the current input. But this is not the case; I can see in my logs that fields are being skipped yet the input is still clearing.

It might be better to log when you set the data, instead of when you skip. The issue is some fields are being cleared, so log every time they are set so you can identify times when the field is being set when it shouldn't be.

> Is there a way that setting `instance.foo` could cause `instance.bar` to be reset?

Not that I'm aware of. It would help if you can provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Change isn't fired on each keypress. For text inputs it doesn't fire until they lose focus so it's much like blur, although it won't fire if a field is blurred without the value changing first.

I've gotten into the habit of using this.$set because I've hit lots of occasions when setting a property manually gets Vue in a muddle. Is there a specific reason not to use it?

Good point about the logging. I'm going to dig into that and see if it throws anything up. If not I'll look at getting a MCVE up. Thanks again.

Comment: If you’re getting into situations where assigning to a property manually doesn’t work, then it just means you haven’t declared all properties upfront for Vue to make them reactive. Using `$set` doesn’t fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Just coming back to this problem. Yes I am using `$set` because this.instance is initially set to be an empty object - it doesn't know what properties it will have until they are returned from the API. You said that using `$set` doesn't fix the underlying problem, but it makes the property reactive which is what I want. Is there a reason _not_ to be using it?

Comment: Using `$set` everywhere may work, but it's a mess. Every time you want to assign to a property of `instance` you *must* use `$set` in case that property didn't exist. Forgetting to do that in one place can make a tricky bug to find. Is `fieldNames` provided by the API too? Your `setFormData` method doesn't use the `data` parameter and `value` is not declared. You can avoid using `$set` by assigning to `this.instance` the complete data object returned from the first API call, then it'll become reactive (the problem is Vue cannot detect when *new properties are added to a reactive object*).